# Google sheets grouping function in excel equivalent or workaround?

Tags: google-sheets

I know you can't do it in Google sheets. I think the grouping function in Excel is one of the most useful things out there with the ability to expand or collapse rows and columns by grouping them.

Has anybody found a good work around for the grouping feature in Excel? If so, please share.